# Why is my Excel not recognizing the numbers with dollar sign?

Tags: excel, ms-office

My other computers work just fine, doing all calculations with the numbers with the dollar sign but one of my computers cannot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The cell should be in text format if you're getting a `#VALUE!` error.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is:

```
=E10+E11
```

`E10` is a string `"--"`
 `E11` is also a string `"--"`.

Summing two string values will give you `#VALUE`.

Try to use `ISNUMBER` function to check if is a string in the cell and convert the string to number. You can use a formula like:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,VALUE(A1))
```

In this way, it will work on both machines.

Comment: your problem might be some other part, if E10 or E11 are also formulas, you should show us also those formulas

Comment: Yes, the problem is why does the Excel on this computer automatically sees all numbers with dollar sign as strings. It cannot recognize them as numbers before I delete the dollar signs. Other Excels  automatically see them as numbers.

Comment: What version on MS Excel is on that machine versus the other machines? If that machine uses an old version, you can try an upgrade.